# Android Memory issue

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Hi
 i have doubt about about gc. suppose that if am using 5 static button with some images as their background,if am finish the application then the memory associated with the button would release or not ?

Comment: can you write more about "static buttons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android won't "kill" your application unless the memory is filled up enough to restrict any new apps from opening. even then too, your apps' state will be saved in a bundle and then the app will be removed from the memory.

Answer (score 0):

as gc works randomly and ur memory is released as soonas new memory needed.thr is no fixed time to collect garbage but after application finishes it will br freed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the GC is smart enough to release the memory you allocate as soon as it's no longer needed - it would be useless otherwise!